Non-const global value as const, C
I want to define a non constant global value, modify it in a function and use it as constant in other functions.
I don't specifically want to pass it as argument, which I already do.
This is an example I wrote of a global value passed as argument too.
I don't like it, as I can just define it in the main scope and pass it as constant argument.
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int value[2]={0};

void myfun(const int* const value){
    printf("%d \n", value[1]);
}

int main(){

    value[1] = 1;
    myfun(value);

    return 0;
}

This is an in-between step though. I wish to let that value global and use it in myfun only as constant, without passing it as argument. Is there a directive which will help it?
I can't copy the entire array. It's quite big (GB order).
This is both for debug purposes (constant need to be constant) and for performance as well.

It's not a constant, so just use it as a non-constant and don't worry about it.  If you're convinced it needs to be declared constant, then write a generator program that generates the declaration and initialization list, use it to create a .c source file, and declare it in a corresponding .h file.

I think the simplest option is to only externally expose a pointer to the array contents:
#include <stdio.h>

extern const int * const value;

void myfun(){
    printf("%d \n", value[1]);
}

/*
 * The static and dynamic initialization below can be in a compilation unit 
 * isolated from the compilation units where the read-only value is required.
 */

static int value_priv[2] = {0};
const int * const value = value_priv;

int main(){

    value_priv[1] = 1;
    myfun();

    return 0;
}

Sure, the code that is given read-only access could gain write access to the array contents by performing some type casting shenanigans. If that is a concern, access to the array contents could be allowed only through function calls, but  that would have the overhead of requiring extra function calls.

Your requirements are contradicting:

I want to define a non constant global value, modify it in a function and use it as constant in other functions.

If it must be "global" then that in itself implies that everyone can access it. You can restrict the access in various ways, by declaring it static or by using a design with incomplete struct types. That does however involve passing a pointer to the variable around, but you don't want that either. So now can do.
A sensible compromise if re-entrancy isn't a concern, might be to declare it as a local static inside a function:
const int* do_stuff_with_x (const int* something)
{
  static int x [2];

  if(something != NULL)
  {
    x[0] = *something; // writes to the variable only happen here
  }
  else
  {} // the function was called just for the purpose of obtaining access to the variable

  return x;  // this is OK since the variable has static storage duration
}

Examples of usage:
int something = 123;

// update and read the variable both at once:
const int* ptr = do_stuff_with_x(&something);

// only update the variable:
(void) do_stuff_with_x(&something);

// only read the variable:
const int* ptr = do_stuff_with_x(NULL);

